# get the images attached to a post but not the featured image in wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, post

```
 $attachments = array(

        'post_type' => 'portfolio',

        'order' => 'ASC',

        'posts_per_page' => '-1'

      //  'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()

     );

$main_qury = new WP_Query($attachments);

$mate=$main_qury->posts;


        foreach ( $mate as $attachment ) {

        //    $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );

            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );

          //  echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($thumbimg);

        }
```

i want to get only those images who are not featured but now i m getting image with post content...how can i separate post content with an image...

Comment: Might this be what you need? http://themehybrid.com/plugins/get-the-image  I've used it for adding post images to the excerpt (which strips images) in a custom theme.

Comment: sory but it is not Compatible..

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why you're attempting to use a WP_Query like that.

Try this instead:

```
global $post;

$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'exclude'        => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
) );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
    }
}
```

Replace large in `wp_get_attachment_image()` with whatever size you want to use.

Comment: +1 since it works for me as is, only that `global $post;` isn't needed for me (neither for anyone attempting to run it from within the loop i guess).